# Multiple downloads jquery

Tags: jquery

I have code that will download multiple files when triggered. Somehow, multiple download works in Chrome on my local machine, but not in Firefox. It only gets the last clicked radio button. This happens in production as well.

```
function(path, files){
  link = document.createElement(‘a’)
  files = [];
  files.push(path)

  for(var i = 0; files.length; i++) {
    link.href = path;
    link.click();
  }
}
```

```
     <div class="modal fade file_upload_modal" role="dialog" width="50px">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
            <center><h2>DOWNLOADABLE FORMS</h2></center>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
          <table class="center" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
              <td class="bold">Select a form: <br><br></td>
            </tr>
            {% for download in downloadfiles %}
            <tr>
              <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{ download.file_name }}" value="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ download.document }}">  {{ download.file_name }}<br></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center" id="download_upload">Download</button>
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-update-download").on('click', function(){
    $(".file_upload_modal").modal("show");
  });

  $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(){
    var checked = $(this).val();
    var count = 0;
    $("#download_upload").on('click', function(){
      count++;
      if (count == 1){
        files = [];
        $.get(downloadFiles(checked, files));
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(".file_upload_modal").modal("hide");
      }
    });
  });
});

function downloadFiles(path, files){
  files.push(path);

  var link=document.createElement('a');

  for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
      link.href = path;
      link.download = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      link.click();
    }
    }
    </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Here's the code I created for downloading multiple files, this works fine on local as what I posted above but it not work on other browser.

Comment: I don't see any radio buttons. Please include all [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) needed to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @showdev I have updated the description thanks

Comment: @denmg: I guess this issue is not with the code, but it's related to the setting present in mozilla firefox. Have a look at the url: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=198284 OR https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/992338 . Google Chrome too have a setting for allowing simultaneous downloads. Reference url: https://ccm.net/faq/32938-google-chrome-allow-websites-to-perform-simultaneous-downloads OR https://www.howtogeek.com/428416/how-to-enabledisable-multiple-file-downloads-in-chrome/ OR https://kb.globalscape.com/Knowledgebase/11236/Chrome-wont-download-multiple-files

Comment: @denmg: Also check for any console errors while browsing website in mozilla firefox

Comment: @prasad I did not see any errors while browsing but the worse part when the code is live on production, even chrome behaves that way say I clicked multiple files the last checkbox I click is the only file that is downloaded. There when I click network during downloading gives an error.

Comment: @denmg Did you went through the reference url's given to you regarding browser settings? If yes did it helped you?

Comment: I did, somehow, it works only locally. But in live its not.